# Neural nets with custom loss function depending on inputs?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions

I'm trying to make a custom loss function for my neural network.

Each of my data point $i$ has a set of input parameters and an output coefficient $p_i$.

My goal is to have a neural net which minimizes $J=-\prod p_i^{a_i}$ where $a_i$ is $1$ or $0$, the output of the sigmoid function at the last layer of my network ($a_i=1$ iff the NN output is $>0.5$, else $a_i=0$). Note that if yout take the log of the function above, I'm trying to opimize $J=-\sum log(p_i)a_i$ where $log(p_i)$ are constants.

Currently, I've simplified my problem where $p'_i=1$ iff $p_i\geq1$, else $p'_i=0$, which allows me to use the standard loss funcion $J'=-\frac{1}{m}\sum p'_ilog(a'_i)+(1-p'_i)log(1-a'_i)$ where $a'_i$ is the output of the NN. However using a custom loss function should yield better results: my real end goal is to minimize the $J$ described above, so for example it's okay to include data points near $p_i=0.99$ if it includes a lot points $p_i>1$ thus making $-\prod p_i^{a_i}$ lower (so this is binary classification parametrized by the value of $p_i$)

I really can't figure out how to have custom loss function which are not derivable functions. All the ressources I could find use well defined functions to compute $\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial W_i}$ and  $\dfrac{\partial J}{\partial b}$ (where the linear part of the neurons computes $WX+b$) (e.g. http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs5740/2016sp/resources/backprop.pdf)

Could anyone points me toward the right ressources to do so please? Thanks.

**Edit**: after reading the comments, it seems I should use a surrogate function and according to http://www.deeplearningbook.org/contents/optimization.html (p 273), I should use the negative log likelihood.

However, doing so in the equation above gives me : $ J = \sum log(p_i)log(a_i) $ and this doesn't make sense to me: I'm OK for the cases when $a_1\approx 0$, BUT if $a_i\approx1$ then $log(p_i)log(a_i)\approx0$, and in that case if $log(p_i)<0$, I expected my loss to increase? Using the negative log likelihood seems to make $J$ ignores cases where $a_i=1$?

Shouldn't the function $$J=\sum log(p_i)log(1-a_i)$$ be more appropriate?

**Edit 2**: herrrr thats actually the same function, OK, case closed.

Comment: What do you mean by p > 2? You are doing binary classification right? Then surely p is between 0 and 1? And if you want to use back propagation, then your loss has to be differentiable.

Comment: You appear to be asking about a weighted variant of 0-1 loss. This problem in known to be NP-hard. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365444/why-is-a-0-1-loss-function-intractable , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization ,  and also https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.0729

Comment: @Tom thank you, I've edited my post to make it more understandable

Comment: @olooney thanks I'm looking at it. Indeed, I should drop all the stuff about non linearity for simplification and just try to find a loss function which can be optimized. I'm looking at it. This is weird though that even $\sum a_i log(p_i)=\sum P_i a_i$ can't be optimized (taking the log of J above) :/

Comment: Maybe you can look at policy gradients from RL? What do you mean by the function cannot be optimized, looks like you can just take the derivative? (I am slightly confused.. )

Comment: @Tom the issue is that $a_i$ is not the output of the network, but a 0-1 loss function with the output of the network as input. So it seems that olooney was right :/ if anyone has an idea for a good approximation of a 0-1 loss function in my case it would be nice to know please :)