# Understanding Sequential Model-Based Optimization for machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian, hyperparameter

One of the hyperparameter tunning approaches that I came across recently is Sequential Model-Based Optimization (SMBO), which is a very smart approach that uses previous iterations in order to find the best values for the hyperparameter.

I just want to make sure I understand it right. So there are several steps and factors for this algorithm, I'll talk about them and at the end I'll add a scheme to summarize it, please correct me if I'm wrong:

1. Build the domain that has the ranges of values that we pick for each hyperparameter. Nothing special here, excpet that we can refer to this domain as a probability distribution that will change with each iteration (when new data comes along).
2. Objective function: this is the function that we want to minimize or maximize (like loss function for example). But we don't use it that much because it's computationally costly and slow, so we use the surrogate.
3. The surrogate "mimics" the objective function, and it evaluates the current values of the hyperparameters.
4. Selection function: based on the surrogate function evaluations, the selection function will now pick new values for the hyperparameters to test.
5. Now, we test those new values in the real objective function and not in the surrogate function as in step 3.
6. we get the REAL score, and we add it to the "History"
7. we repeat. Now the surrogate and the selection functions are updated based on the first round (the History).

Here is a scheme that I prepared to sum it up more or less:

[image]

Did I describe the steps correctly? is the scheme ok?

Answer (score 0):

It looks good to me, but I'll clarify some points that could create ambiguity for future reference.

Let's suppose that you have a training dataset $\mathcal{D}$, a validation dataset $\mathcal{V}$, and a model $g = g_w(\lambda,\mathcal{D})$ with parameters $w$ and hyperparameters $\lambda$ in an hypothesis space $\Lambda$.
To evaluate the model performance after training, we use a metric $M$ on the validation set.

> Objective function: this is the function that we want to minimize or maximize (like loss function for example)

The **objective function** (also called response function) $$f(\lambda) = M(g(\lambda,\mathcal{D}),\mathcal{V})$$ is the value of a metric  obtained by a learned model $g$ with (fixed) hyperparameters $\lambda$ on a dataset $\mathcal{D}$.

- In cases like regression you can use MSE as loss function and also as the metric $M$, but in most cases $M$ is another function
- In gradient-based learning the loss function is (almost everywhere) differentiable, while $f(\lambda)$ can be not differentiable or not optimizable through GD (Think about [accuracy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365444/why-is-a-0-1-loss-function-intractable?rq=1))
- Evaluating $f(\lambda)$ is expensive since it requires to train each model to convergence and then evaluate the metrics on the validation set $\mathcal{V}$. Expecially for deep model, this process can require several days, so it's not feasible to evaluate all combinations of hyperparameters $\lambda_1 \dots \lambda_n \in \Lambda$ (Grid search), and hyperparmeters can also be continuous.

This is why we want to find a *lightweight* **predictor** $\hat{f}(\lambda)$ that estimates the value $f(\lambda$), before the *expensive* training. To train this predictor, you initially sample a casual combination of hyperparameters $\lambda_i \in \Lambda$, then you compare the estimated value $f(\lambda)$ with the metric $M$ obtained after training and evaluating the model with hyperparameters $\lambda_i$. The update is done with Bayes Rule

The **selection function** (also called acquisition function) tells us which regions of the hyperparameter space are more *promising*, i.e the regions where the model is predicted to perform well and/or the regions where there is more uncertainity. To guarantee a good search, we want to find a compromise between *exploration* and *exploitation*

[image]

The selection function can be modeled as

- the probability that a set of hyperparameters $\lambda_j \in \Lambda$ improves upon the current best value (*probability of improvement*). An issue with this is that you don't estimate how much the new set of hyperparameter will improve
- the **expected improvement** $$\mathbb{E}[I(\lambda)] = \mathbb{E}[\max(0, f_{\text{min}} - \hat{f}(\lambda))]$$

You want to try the hyperparameter values that maximize the expected improvement under some **budget**, and you also need to account for hyperparamter combinations that are more expensive to evaluate than others, so we can define the **expected improvement per second**

### References

[[1](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-25566-3_40)] Hutter, Frank, Holger H. Hoos, and Kevin Leyton-Brown. "Sequential model-based optimization for general algorithm configuration." Learning and Intelligent Optimization: 5th International Conference, LION 5, Rome, Italy, January 17-21, 2011. Selected Papers 5. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2011.

[[2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008306431147#citeas)] Jones, D.R., Schonlau, M. & Welch, W.J. Efficient Global Optimization of Expensive Black-Box Functions. Journal of Global Optimization 13, 455–492 (1998). https://doi.org/10.1023/A:1008306431147